# Automatically add parameter to embedded youtube video - Regular Expressions help? (PHP, Wordpress)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, youtube

I am using a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-favorite-video-posts/) that imports the favourites from a youtube channel as posts in wordpress.

It works great and creates posts with the content:

```
<iframe width="670" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, there are no options to add embed parameters such as:

```
&showinfo=0
```

to the embed parameter.

Thus I am considering loading the content into a variable and running a regular expression on it to add the parameter &showinfo=0 after videoid.

```
$video = get_the_content();    
echo preg_replace('embed/(?:(?!").)*', "$1&showinfo=0", $video);
```

I have always struggled with regular expressions, I'm sure the above is not really the right expression. Any help or even another suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you have some syntax wrong.

```
preg_replace('@embed/([^"&]*)@', 'embed/$1&showinfo=0', $video);
```

`[^"&]*` means 'any number of characters that are not double quotes or an ampersand', the latter character I added just in case your plugin generates a link with some extra parameters in it that you weren't expecting.

Comment: Ah thank you, that is indeed the perfect syntax. Now I'm having a very odd issue where echoing the preg_replace outputs nothing! If I echo $video, it outputs the iframe and everything, but after the preg_replace, it is empty. I can't understand why.

Comment: You're right.  I forgot that `preg_replace` requires the expression to have a delimiter at both ends.  The updated code should work.

Comment: Ah perfect!! Works 100%, funny enough now i just realized that with iframe embedding, these parameters aren't even valid! Sigh... but a huge help anyways, thank you!